# Find all numbers not in a range

Tags: shell-script

I have a file with following content :-

```
2
4
5
```

and have range, say 1 to 5 .  I need a shell script whose output will
be 1,3. That is the numbers which are not present in the file and within the range.

How can I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do task just by `grep`

```
seq 5 | fgrep -vxf <(tr ' ' '\n' < file)
```

- `tr` transforms file string in one-number-on-line output
- `<()` command substitution (command's output reads as file)
- `-f` option of `grep` means that pattern(s) will read from file
- `-x` option means "match whole line" for for example `1` will do not match `11` or `21`
- `-v` options reverse pattern match
- `seq` produce list of numbers from `1` (omitted as default) upto `5` separated by newline

EDITED:
If your file already consist 1 number by 1 line you can omit `tr`

```
seq 5 | fgrep -vxf file
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, you are right, I forgot numbers with two or more digits. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
comm -13 <(sort file) <(seq 1 5 | sort) | sort -n
```

The `comm` command reports common lines among (lexically) sorted files. Without any option, it gives three columns:

1. Lines found only in first file
2. Lines found only in the second file
3. Lines common to both files.

You pass `-1`, `-2`, `-3` options to suppress the corresponding columns. So `-13` leaves *lines found only in `<(seq 1 5 | sort)` output*.

Answer (score 0):

one sample (and not perfect) solution will looks like:

```
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
flag=1
for j in `cat filename_with_numbers`
do
if [ $i -eq $j ]
then flag=0
fi
done
if [ $flag -eq 1 ]
then echo $i
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for n in `cat in.txt`
do
    if [ $i -ne $n ]
    then
        echo $i >> result.txt
    else
        ((i++))
    fi
done
```

Comment: this will make i to get values only between 1 and the number of the elements of in array. So it not work!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#make a range of numbers
range=$(seq -s' ' 5)
#make a copy of range
tmp_range=$range
#loop the content
for i in $(echo 2 4 5)
do
  #loop the range
  for j in $range
  do
    if [ $i -eq $j ]
    then
        #delete in the copy if match
        tmp_range=$(echo $tmp_range|sed "s/$i//")
        #exit this loop and continue the first loop if match
        continue 2
    fi
  done
done
echo $tmp_range
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 3 ]
then
    echo "Usage: ./script.sh min_val max_val filename"
    exit 1
fi

for ((i=$1;i<=$2;i++))
do 
    grep -q $i $3 
    if [ $? -eq 1 ] 
    then 
        echo $i 
    fi 
done
```